# Running user written code in a javascript game

Tags: javascript, node.js

Looking for some direction and help. I am new to JavaScript and NodeJS and have not been able to find anything online on how to do this. I've written a minesweeper game in JavaScript and would like to be able to inject user written code into the game loop instead of taking inputs.

The main problem I am running into is getting access to the methods I've built into the game class. Here's the code.

---

```
class Game {
    constructor() {
        this.GameBoard = new MineSweeperBoard(true);

        autoBind(this);
    }

    pop(x ,y){
        this.GameBoard.pop(x, y);
    }

    flag(x, y){
        this.GameBoard.flag(x,y);
    }

    removeFlag(x,y){
        this.GameBoard.RemoveFlag(x,y);
    }

    checkWin(){
        this.GameBoard.CheckForWin();
    }

    getGameBoard(){
        return this.GameBoard.GetRevealedGameBoard()
    }

}


function StartGame() {
    let CurrentGame = new Game();

    let win = false;

    while(CurrentGame.GameBoard.RunGame) {
        //User Code here
        
        *User written code should run right about here.*

        // Check win condition
        if(CurrentGame.checkWin()){
            win = true;
        }

    }
```

---

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

*** Edit ***

To answer some question that have been asked.

1: This isn't secure: Yes I understand there are potential security implications to running user generated code. As of right now that is not a concern as this is mostly a proof of concept.

2: Why do I want to do this: Because I want to see if it's possible and I know others have found ways to securely run user code (i.e. Screeps). Right now I would like to see what is possible.

Comment: Tip: If you're using capital style like `Game` for your classes, keep your instances lower-case. `CurrentGame` implies that it too is a class, which it is not. Don't forget that [JavaScript now has "getters"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) meaning that functions like `getGameBoard()` could and arguably should be a getter if that's the intent.

Comment: Maybe try `eval`... but why do you want to execute user-written code? What are you hoping to achieve by this?

Comment: Why do you want and/or need user-supplied code? If this is running on a server you really cannot allow such things. In a browser you can be more lenient but you must be very careful how and when that technique is used.